# How do I change the remote frequency options in my ceiling fan?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

My Hampton Bay ceiling fan remote control is interfering with my neighbours.  Inside the remote there are switches to adjust the remote frequency.

Where in the fan do I make the corresponding adjustment? Do I have to take the fan down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switches for the fan are either in the lower bell housing or on top of the motor assembly.

Check the lower bell first.  There should be 3 or 4 small screws holding this on, remove them and carefully remove the light assembly.  Look inside the bell to find the RF receiver, the switches are on this (you may have to pull it out to access the switches).

If the RF receiver is not there it is probably on the motor assembly, in which case the fan will have to be taken down.  Even if you have to take the fan down you should not have to disconnect any wiring, there should be a hook on the assembly so you can hang it from the mounting bracket while you adjust the switches.

Depending on the ceiling clearance you may have to remove the blades, then remove the decorative ring near the ceiling.  Carefully remove the screws that hold the fan to the mounting bracket, you should be able to hang the fan from a hook on the mounting bracket (so you don't have to hold the fan while you work).  Inside this assembly you should see the RF receiver, adjust the switches and re-mount the fan.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to take the fan down, but you will need to go inside the housing and find the receiver. The receiver and your remote need to have the dip switches adjusted in order to change the frequency. It is likely that your dip switches are set to factory default and so is the other fan that is also being controlled by the same remote (or vica versa)

Here is a good article I came across recently that talks about [how to change the dip switch settings](https://remotecontrolplace.com/hampton-bay-ceiling-fan-remote-controls/how-to-change-frequency-of-ceiling-fan-remote/) on both. It walks you through the whole process

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your fan.  There will be a little control unit installed in the base of the ceiling fan, that is wired to the motor.  With most fans, you can take off the base that covers the electrical box (above the fan if if is hanging from a short rod).  There is usually one or two screws that hold this one.  It is purely decorative, so do not worry about it holding the fan up.  Under this, you will see the fan rod hanging from a metal structure.  Usually inside this, there will be a control unit.

They are typically about 4-5 inches long, 2-3 inches with, and less than an inch think.  You may be able to change the DIP switches without removing it, but you may have to take the fan off to  pull it out.  It just depends how much space is in there.

good Luck!